# How to extract specific from the url using regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract specific number and text from the url

```
import re
text = """https://bingo.render.com/vegenpropertymanagementllc.messio.com/2231/workOrders/9552?idp_type"""
work_order_id = re.search(r'workOrders/(\d+)/',text)
print(work_order_id)
company = re.search(r'.com/(.*)/',text)
print(company.group(1))
```

Required solution:

```
company = vegenpropertymanagementllc.messio.com
work_order_id = 9552
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about requirements. If "company" is always the 1st part as shown then just turning your capture group content into non-greedy `.*?` should work.

Comment: You don't need *re* for this. Easier to use *parse()* function from *urllib*

Answer (score 2):

You can isolate the two required values easily using urllib.parse as follows:

```
from urllib import parse

URL = 'https://bingo.render.com/vegenpropertymanagementllc.messio.com/2231/workOrders/9552?idp_type'

_, company, *_, work_order_id = parse.urlsplit(URL).path.split('/')

print(f'{company=}')
print(f'{work_order_id=}')
```

**Output:**

```
company='vegenpropertymanagementllc.messio.com'
work_order_id='9552'
```